# SWT user control design decision

Tags: java, swt, composite

Hypothetical question:

What about this SWT design decision that to make a custom compound widget I have to subclass Composite? Is that really wise?

Wouldn't it be better if SWT had a UserControl class like in Win Forms or something?

When I subclass Composite my custom widget get the Composite interface, even if it is not intended to be used as a Composite by clients. That's kind of bad. The same is true for some SWT widgets, like Spinner.

Is there a good way around this?

And, most interesting: Do anyone know the motivation for this design decision?

Comment: Can you use delegation instead of inheritance?

Comment: This was my thought also, that it would be cleaner to use delegation in some way, maybe extend Control and have an internal Composite. But the SWT guidelines says you should only extend Composite or Canvas. Canvas don't seem like a good fit either, most of the time.

Comment: Since I am doing a lot of development in Swing I just ended up wrapping all the Swing components I use since the interfaces are so bulky and bad for mocking.

Comment: In SWT FAQ is nice explanation of subclassing [Why can't I subclass SWT widgets like Button and Table?](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#subclassing) also article [Creating Your Own Widgets using SWT](http://eclipse.org/articles/Article-Writing%20Your%20Own%20Widget/Writing%20Your%20Own%20Widget.htm) may answer some of your questions or doubts..

Comment: I've seen those, they are good. To discourage extension of the standard widgets seems like a good idea, but making custom controls extend either Composite or Canvas seems a bit weird I think. But it's not a big problem anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You could look at the source code for `org.eclipse.swt.custom.CCombo` to see how SWT deals with this problem internally, as `CCombo` extends from `Composite`.  Here's how they handle `setLayout()`, for example:

```
/**
 * Sets the layout which is associated with the receiver to be
 * the argument which may be null.
 * <p>
 * Note: No Layout can be set on this Control because it already
 * manages the size and position of its children.
 * </p>
 *
 * @param layout the receiver's new layout or null
 *
 * @exception SWTException <ul>
 *    <li>ERROR_WIDGET_DISPOSED - if the receiver has been disposed</li>
 *    <li>ERROR_THREAD_INVALID_ACCESS - if not called from the thread that created the receiver</li>
 * </ul>
 */
public void setLayout (Layout layout) {
    checkWidget ();
    return;
}
```

Comment: Whoops, they don't even throw when someone calls this method. You don't even get to know that you have done something wrong.

Comment: And my point is that this seems like a questionable design to me. Because you publicly inherit the Composite interface on a widget that isn't supposed to function as a Composite. But maybe there is a good reason, it would be interesting to know what it is.

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own `NonCompositeUserControl` class:

```
public class NonCompositeUserControl extends Composite {
    @Override
    public void setLayout(Layout layout) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("This control is not really a composite")
    }
    // similarly for other methods
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can add a runtime check like this. But it would be clearer and less error prone if you didn't need to subclass Composite at all. For example, you can still pass this class as a parent when you create another widget.